# Building an IRC bot using PHP, need some help

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, irc

I am using the [a SmartIRC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsmartirc/) library for this.
What I need to be able to do is have the bot running and accepting commands from users, and also listening on a UDP socket.
I get data sent through the UDP socket that I need to analyze, sort into MySQL tables and such.
I need that UDP data to be available to my BOT.

So the problem is, whenever I open a UDP socket it listens to all the data in a 'while' loop.
So it means that the IRC bot itself is un-functional until the loop is over and closed.
I thought about using some kind of a multi-threading solution, but I am not sure how.
I need to find some way to spawn a new thread of the UDP socket, and send that data to my currently running bot. ah, no clue.

Any ideas?
Hopefully I explained it enough so you guys can understand what the hell I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you chose PHP for this task?  Eggdrops are the preferred IRC bot.  The downside is that you would need to learn TCL to write scripts for the bot unless you wanted to write your own compiled module (I don't remember what language those are written in).  I would say PHP is not the ideal language for this.

Comment: Well I chose PHP because I have knowledge in it. I do not know any other languages good enough to create a bot in them. If I wont find a solution for this, I will probably learn Java real quick and create a bot using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're listening for data in a while loop.  When I have used SmartIRC in the past I use `$irc->registerActionhandler()` for the user commands and then call `$irc->listen( )`, that way the library handles it all for you.

Some good examples of using SmartIRC can be found [here](http://wiki.shellium.org/w/Writing_an_IRC_bot_in_PHP), hopefully they will help you.

Comment: I am trying to listen for UDP data from a remote server, that is not related to IRC at all. So I am not sure how this will help.